# Find all solutions to $4x^2+6x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions to $4x^2+6x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$

I think it has no solutions but I am not sure how to show this.

Comment: You could always just try $x = 0,1,2,\ldots,12$.

Comment: Is there another way? What if there is a large modulus?

Comment: We use a "general" approach. The congruence holds if and only if $16x^2+24x+4\equiv 0\pmod{13}$. This is the case if and only if $(4x+3)^2\equiv 5\pmod{13}$. Now we ask whether $5$ is a quadratic residue of $13$. 
The number $13$ is small, so we can test by checking whether $t^2\equiv 5\pmod{13}$ for $t=1,2,3,4,5,6$. Or else (overkill) we can use a Legendre symbol calculation. This might be useful for primes substantially larger than $13$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nice. Legendre symbol $\left( \frac{5}{13} \right) =-1$. So $5$ is not a residue.

Comment: Yes, a short Reciprocity argument. Overkill for $13$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algebraic solution.

$$4x^2+6x+1\equiv 0 \pmod{13}$$
$$10\cdot(4x^2+6x+1)\equiv 0 \pmod{13}$$
$$x^2+8x+10\equiv 0 \pmod{13}$$
$$x^2+8x+16\equiv 6 \pmod{13}$$
$$(x+4)^2\equiv 6 \pmod{13}$$

Then we look for a number from $0$ to $12$ whose square modulo $13$ is $6$. However, there is none. This could be confirmed with [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity), which would be need for numbers much larger than $13$.

Therefore, your equation has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have $4x^2+6x+1 = (2x+3/2)^2-5/4$. Hence,
\begin{align}
4x^2+6x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{13} \implies (2x+3/2)^2-5/4 \equiv 0 \pmod{13}
\end{align}
This simplifies into
\begin{align}
(4x+3)^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{13}
\end{align}
This has no solutions, since
$$5^{(13-1)/2}\pmod{13} \equiv 5^6\pmod{13} \equiv (25)^3 \pmod{13} \equiv-1\pmod{13}$$

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square: $4x^2+6x+1=(2x+3)^2-8$

$2x+3$ is an integer so we can let $a=2x+3$.

Then: 
$$
a^2\equiv 8 \pmod {13} 
$$

You can check if this has a solution with a simple remainder table:
[image]

Comment: We need only the first half of the table by $\,(-x)^2\equiv x^2,\,$ e.g. $\, 11^2\equiv (-2)^2\equiv 2^2\ $ The negation symmetry is obvious in the table: the values are symmetric around the midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\ 13\!:\,\ 0\equiv (2x)^2\overbrace{+\,3}^{\large -10}\,(2x)+1\equiv X^2-10X+1\equiv (X\!-\!5)^2+2$

But $\ (X\!-\!5)^2\equiv -2\,\underset{(\ \ )^{\Large 6}}\Rightarrow\,(X\!-\!5)^{12}\equiv (-2)^6\equiv -1\not\equiv 1,\,$ contra Fermat. So it has no roots.